# After I've foolishly gave Ubuntu only 50Gb, is it possible to resize the partition, and how?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I've decided that I want to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10. Windows for games, and Ubuntu for projects, programming and other stuff. Now, first of all, how was I supposed to know how much memory would each of these systems need at the time of installation? I guess I had to think before I acted... Anyway, When that slider showed up, I slid it all the way to the right, giving Ubuntu only 50Gb, I think. Now, did Windows get all other ~600Gb my laptop has, or did I accidentally create a "shared" partition only for files? Anyway, what should I do if I decide that I need more memory on my Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, back up your important Windows and Ubuntu data to external media and test that the media is readable on other systems. If you don't, [you may regret it](https://superuser.com/search?q=recover+partition)

Then use partition management tools (there are many, e.g. [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/), [ntfsresize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ntfsresize)) to resize the partitions.

In my experience, NTFS partitions sometimes need to have chkdsk run on them when they are expanded. In theory a good partitioning tool should expand the filesystem as well as the partition.